# Solving a three-variable implicit function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot n vs theta1 from the function tan(n*theta1) + tan(n*theta2) + tan(n*thetas)= 0 in MATLAB; where n, theta1 and theta2 are variables and thetas is given. Can anyone give any pointers how to do so ?

I have tried using ezplot. It didn't work.

Next, I used this bit of code,

```
c = 1;
thetas = pi/4;
for n = 1.01:0.01:3.50
    for theta1 = pi/2 : 0.01 : 5*pi/6
        for theta2 = 0: 0.01: pi/2
            if(tan(n*theta1) + tan(n*theta2) + tan(n*thetas) >= -0.0001 && tan(n*theta1) + tan(n*theta2) + tan(n*thetas) <= 0.0001 && (n*theta1) ~= pi/2 ...
                    && (n*theta2) ~= pi/2 && (n*thetas) ~= pi/2)
                ns(c) = n;
                theta1s(c) = theta1;
                theta2s(c) = theta2;
                c = c + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And I tried to plot the result using the plot command. Didn't work out either. Mostly the plot should come as three different curves for every given value of thetas.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work? -

```
%%// Data (Random numbers)
thetas_array = [2 4 6]; %// Put different thetas here
theta2 = 2:2:20;
n = 1:10;

figure,
for k = 1:numel(thetas_array)

    thetas = thetas_array(k);

    %%// Since tan(n*theta1) + tan(n*theta2) + tan(n*thetas)= 0;
    theta1 =  (1./n).*atan(- tan(n.*theta2) - tan(n.*thetas));

    subplot(3,1,k), plot(n,theta1), xlabel('n'), ylabel(strcat('theta1 [thetas = ',num2str(thetas),']'));
end
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Other than this code requiring equi-dimensional n and theta2 vectors, this code works as it should. But according to a paper, I am supposed to get 3 lines per graph per thetas. Which I am not getting.

Comment: So you would like to have only one graph that would have all three plots for three thetas?